# Need of JWT expiresIn field to display on console

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, express-jwt

how to get expiry time in JWT?
I want to notice every user the expiration time of login token, right now i could display their userId, email id but unable to display expiresIn timings. Please point out where should i edit my code to display expiresIn field.

```
 router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ username: req.body.username })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              username: user[0].username,
              email: user[0].email,
              userId: user[0]._id,
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: "10h"
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token,
            userId: user[0]._id,
            expiresIn: user[0].exp,
          });
        }
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

This is the output i m getting as of now.

> {
>       "message": "Auth successful",
>       "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImRhcnNoYW4iLCJlbWFpbCI6ImRhcnNoYW5hbi4yNEBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJ1c2VySWQiOiI1YjU3MTcxNmRjODlhYzZiNGUyY2E0MTciLCJpYXQiOjE1Mzg5ODEyOTYsImV4cCI6MTUzONn0.k0PVole653f_pB3CrQLtdUmv7-c00x1irbQph2i2XaE",
>       "userId": "5b571716dc89ac6b4e2ca417" ,
>   "email": "darsh4@gmail.com"}

Comment: your code doesn't mach your output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like you have not sent the proper `expiration` response.

```
 let expiration = '10h'
 const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              username: user[0].username,
              email: user[0].email,
              userId: user[0]._id,
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
              expiresIn: expiration
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token,
            userId: user[0]._id,
            expiresIn: expiration, //set expiration time
          });
```

Reference link that helps you : [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-json-web-tokens-node-js/)

Comment: ll check this method